# Movie with a super intelligent guy who learns Spanish in five minutes from a book and boasts he can levitate things

Tags: identify-this-movie

**!Might say some spoilers!**

I have been trying to find a movie with a super intelligent guy. I don't remember much from the movie cause I was around 10-12 when I saw it in school (I'm 18 now).

Stuff I remember:

1. In one scene he reads a Spanish book and learns the language in less
   than 5min.
2. It was in English.
3. Most of the scenes were played in a farm/country side.
4. In one scene he's in a Carnevale/festival. And he shows some guys
   that he is so smart that he can make stuff levitate. Then one of the
   guys ask why they can't do that and he answers with "Cause you
   haven't unlocked your brain" (or something close to that)
5. He also tries to find a child on an apple farm, and they later find
   him up in a treehouse.
6. In the end of the movie:

   > he dies beside his wife/girlfriend and feels his whole body shutting down.

Comment: If I recall correctly, he learns Portuguese, not Spanish.

Comment: I don't think he ever 'boasted' that he could levitate things. He was pretty reluctant to show his abilities, for fear of how people would respond. In the end, both his abilities and his death was due to a brain tumor, with 'tentacles' or tendrils through his brain, so it couldn't be removed.

Comment: @user1014, you sound like that "doctor" who wanted to cut him up.  *"I'm what everyone can be. Anyone can get here. I'm the possibility. What I'm talking about is the human spirit. That's the challenge. That's the voyage. That's the expedition."*

Comment: @fedorqui That's very common to happen, people get confused with these two languages. Don't know why. Maybe they don't know that Portuguese exists.

Comment: @Nicke who knows... but as a Spanish native speaker I find it important to remind that they are different languages :)

Comment: WTH @Wildcard, where did I say or imply anything about cutting him up? I just repeated what the cause was.

Comment: @user1014 yes, what the "cause" was...according to the doctor who valued cutting up George Malley's brain over anything George might have to say.  George disagreed with the supposed "cause" of his genius being a brain tumor.  See italicized quote in my previous comment.  Perhaps see the movie again.  :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is [**Phenomenon**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117333/) (1996) with John Travolta.

> An ordinary man sees a bright light descend from the sky, and discovers he now has super-intelligence and telekinesis.

> Q: Most of the scenes were played in a farm/country side.
>
> S: George Malley is a kind but average auto mechanic in a small town in Northern California.

---

> Q: In one scene he reads a Spanish book and learns the language in less than 5min. He also tries to find a child on an apple farm, and they later find him up in a treehouse.
>
> A: When Doc is called to aid a sick Portuguese man, George learns the language in minutes and helps translate. He then uses his telekinesis to rescue the man's young relative.